# Query Default network on yammer

Tags: yammer

We have some users with more than one network on yammer, we only have abc.com as company network and many users have private networks(itpor, o365).

We have built app for company users to query items with certain tags and display in gridview but it fails if some users are on different than private network.

Is there a way to set default network for Yammer REST call that only query company network even though user are currently on different network?